# Is it possible to only give ItemDecoration to some items in a recylcerview?

Tags: android

I split my items into 4 sub types in my viewholder and i only want to give the ItemDecoration to 1 sub type, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd just have to check the viewtype in the ItemDecoration implementation.

Comment: Could you show me a example on how to do this?

Comment: Check the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28232909/how-to-selectively-decorate-recyclerview-items?noredirect=1&lq=1) that this has been marked as duplicate and the [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexfu/0f464fc3742f134ccd1e) it refers to.